# Spinner on a screen displaying on another screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am having a spinner on a fragment. Same spinner getting displayed on next fragment when tap on anywhere on screen. How to hide it. Please help

Comment: have you set background to layout file of both fragment? because it may be your screen is overlap with each other.

Comment: Paste code, Where you are displaying second fragment @Aarti verma

Comment: post whatever you have tried.